# Connecting to other database types in the 2sxc module

Tags: mysql, 2sxc

Is there currently anything in the 2sxc module that allows you to connect to other database types? Specifically I would like to connect to a MySQL database. I know you can connect to other tables within the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends a bit on your question. Let's split

**Can you use Razor-Views in 2sxc to visualize data from any kind of database?**

Yes, just use c# code to get the data. Just create the sql-objects or whatever in .net and use that. For example, I wrote about using PetaPoco http://2sxc.org/en/docs/docs/feature/feature/2583

**Can you use non-sql-data in your Visual Query Designer**

Yes, but you'll have to work a bit. The easiest way is to map your my-sql tables in the DNN SQL server. This is a bit like a translation layer, which then let's use use them as if they were in the SQL Server.

A harder way is to create your own data source. Best to inherit the SqlDataSource (which provides a lot of security around parameter injection etc.) https://github.com/2sic/eav-server/blob/master/ToSic.Eav.DataSources/SqlDataSource.cs - and then modify it to use your mysql